# WatchKit context menu shifting interface controller

Tags: ios, menu, interface, contextmenu, watchkit

I seem to be encountering a problem with the latest Xcode 6.3 beta 2.

When I launch the context menu by holding down in simulator it seems to shift my interface controller up and can't seem to figure out why. This problem also happens when I present a view controller when table cell is pressed

Before context menu is launched
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydUjG.png

after context menu is launched
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4qFQ.png

Would this be because I'm using paged navigation? 
or
Would this be just a little bug in the simulator?

I would really appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 1):

For WatchKit development you should be using Xcode 6.2 and not 6.3.

Comment: I actually still seem to be getting this problem. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Are you getting this problem using Xcode 6.2 or just in 6.3?

Comment: That problem is also there when i present an interface. It seems to remove/push the top bar (The bar with time etc.) away also

Comment: It's really weird. It's like it just glitches out and pushed my view up. Maybe it messed up when i went from Xcode 6.2 to Xcode 6.3

Comment: Did you present a page based controller from your original controller?

Comment: Yes from the root controller it loads up a page based controller.

Comment: Ahh, that is different that what I am doing in my app.  I do my menu on my root page base interface controller.  As a test try doing that and see if you still the shift.  If you do, then the problem is most likely in your code, if you don't then it is probably a bug on the Watch. It sounds like you have a complex navigation structure and I would move away from that for quick interactions.

Comment: my project literally has the same code as this guys project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fq-RXhPPRF8